# sympyのlistの使い方(matrix-->list)を教えて下さい。 3点の平面の方程式

Tags: python, sympy

mylist1,mylist2,mylist3を使わない方法を教えて下さい。関数だと助かります。

参考　3点 A(1,1,2),B(0,-2,1),C(3,-1,0) を通る平面の方程式を計算せよ。

https://manabitimes.jp/math/679
http://meg.aalip.jp/python/math01.html
https://atatat.hatenablog.com/entry/sympy12_vectormodule1

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
import itertools
var('x y z')
myTitle="1：外積と法線ベクトルを用いる方法"
N = CoordSys3D('N')
vA= 1*N.i+1*N.j+2*N.k
vB= 0*N.i-2*N.j+1*N.k
vC= 3*N.i-1*N.j+0*N.k
myGaiseki=(vB-vA).cross(vC-vA).to_matrix(N)
mylist1 =[0,0,0]
for i in range(len(mylist1)):
    mylist1[i] = myGaiseki[i, 0]
myxyz    =Matrix([x,y,z])
myvA     =vA.to_matrix(N)
mylist2 =[0,0,0]
for i in range(len(mylist2)):
    mylist2[i] = (myxyz-myvA).transpose()[0, i]
mylist3=0
for i in range(len(mylist2)):
    mylist3 = mylist3+mylist1[i]*mylist2[i]
print("#",myTitle,mylist3/4)
# 1：外積と法線ベクトルを用いる方法 x - y + 2*z - 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from sympy import Plane, factor_list

points = ((1, 1, 2), (0, -2, 1), (3, -1, 0))
fac, equation = factor_list(Plane(*points).equation())
equation = (-1 if fac < 0 else 1) * equation[0][0]

print(equation)

# 
x - y + 2*z - 4
```

Comment: 他の方法でもチャレンジしました。https://qiita.com/mrrclb48z/items/4269b59a97af6bb214c8

Comment: https://qiita.com/mrrclb48z/items/90e6010a2828eeda0810